# SQL issue with using concatenation inside "like"

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I'm trying to use subquery inside "like", sth like this:

```
select * 
from message c  
where c.content like (select concat('%', value, '%') 
                      from objects o 
                      where o.orderid = '70008090102484');
```

and it's returning no results. When I copy paste the output of the select instead of it, it returns one row, so I've tried this:

```
select * 
from message c  
where c.content like concat('%', '123', '%'); - no results

select * 
from message c  
where c.content like '%123%';* - 1 result
```

I've tried with '%' || '123' || '%' and the same result.
Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: "content" field is of type "bytea" - for varchar it works fine, unfortunately, I'm unable to change this field type

Comment: Do a JOIN instead.

Comment: Column `value` data type?

Comment: All three [work just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=61cf437c51a114ab3cd74874dc152d25)

Comment: Value is varchar32

Comment: I tried with a join as well, but the same result - the problem is still in concatenation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it seems to work based on your examples on version 10 up. Below 10 it's not. I'll have to check tomorrow morning which version we're running, but it doesn't seem to work in out setup.

Comment: [Works for 9.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.3&fiddle=aefbdbf00cdfbbc581d8b6a2dda98e24)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added an edit about the "content" value type which seems to be the root cause of the issue

Comment: Well, `LIKE` only works on text (or varchar) values. Not on binary data stored in a `bytea` column. If those are "proper" strings, then why obfuscate the data by storing it in a `bytea` column? I am actually surprised this didn't result in an error.

Comment: Well, it seems too be working when you put it in a single string, e.g. '%123%', but not when you're concatenating for whatever reason...

Answer (score 0):

Your first query can be phrased using exists in a structurally-similar way:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM message c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM objects o
    WHERE c.content LIKE CONCAT('%', o.value, '%') AND
          o.orderid = '70008090102484'
);
```